# What is the purpose of the @ symbol in <groupId>@project.groupId@</groupId>?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jacoco

I'm trying to run 'mvn clean install' in a sub-module of a multi-module project.  The project is [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) but I assume it's more an issue of me not understanding how Maven is being used here than an issue with Jacoco itself.

https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/jacoco-maven-plugin.test/it/it-site/pom.xml

I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Plugin @project.groupId@:jacoco-maven-plugin:@project.version@
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   @project.groupId@:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:@project.version@

I see the following in the [pom](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/jacoco-maven-plugin.test/it/it-site/pom.xml):

```
<groupId>@project.groupId@</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

I'm not familiar with using the @ symbol in `@project.groupId@` although i assume it is somehow supposed to get substituted at runtime.

I can run Maven from the top level pom and I even see `[INFO] Building: it-site/pom.xml` in the log but a target directory is not created there.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: In maven there are property placeholders but those use ${project.version} for example. I'm guess they are using @ somehow (not sure how).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably has something to do with the pom file here: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/jacoco-maven-plugin.test/pom.xml

It is using a plugin called the [maven invoker](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/).

> The Invoker Plugin is used to run a set of Maven projects. The plugin can determine whether each project execution is successful, and optionally can verify the output generated from a given project execution.

And if you read about filtering files with this plugin, [it mentions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/filtering.html):

> POM files selected by the include/exclude patterns. The tokens to be filtered must be enclosed in @...@ to avoid interferences with Maven's normal POM interpolation, i.e. use @project.version@ instead of ${project.version}.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why the Invoker Plugin and filtering is being used here...

The [Spring Boot documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/CONTRIBUTING.html) provides some relevant background on why that is.  Although the docs are for Spring Boot, i think it applies to testing all plugins (which Jacoco is).

> Multi-module Maven builds cannot directly include maven plugins that
> are part of the reactor unless they have previously been built. ...
> The standard build works around this restriction by launching the
> samples via the **maven-invoker-plugin** so that they are not part of the
> reactor.
>
> The sample application are used as integration tests during the build
> (when you mvn install). **Due to the fact that they make use of the
> spring-boot-maven-plugin they cannot be called directly, and so
> instead are launched via the maven-invoker-plugin.**